# Prolog Movie Database

Tags: prolog

I have a the following database of facts:

```
actor(jonny, depp, gender(male)).
actor(bruce, willis, gender(male)).
...

movie(year(1999), title([american,beauty]), cast([actor(kevin, spacey), actor(annette,bening), actor(wes,bentley)])).
movie(year(2001), title([lord,of,the,rings]), cast([actor(orlando, bloom), actor(sean, bean)])).
...
```

I need to write a prolog query to answer the question `what movies were released in or after 1999`

I have tried `movie(Y, M, C), member(Y, [_|year]).`but it just lists all movies in the database. How can i change it so only movie released in or after 1999 are listed?

Comment: When you query `member(Y, [_|year])` it will always succeed by unifying `Y` with `_`. So, of course, you get all the database entries.

Answer (score 2):

As you can use library(lists) for member/2, you can probably also use library(clpfd):

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

Then you can query:

```
?- Y#>=1999, movie(year(Y), M, C).
C = cast([actor(kevin,spacey),actor(annette,bening),actor(wes,bentley)]),
M = title([american,beauty]),
Y = 1999 ? ;
C = cast([actor(orlando,bloom),actor(sean,bean)]),
M = title([lord,of,the,rings]),
Y = 2001
```

Of course with your example (year >= 1999, only two movies in the db) you also get the entire db as answers. If you try a later year:

```
?- Y#>=2000, movie(year(Y), M, C).
C = cast([actor(orlando,bloom),actor(sean,bean)]),
M = title([lord,of,the,rings]),
Y = 2001
```

If you take a closer look at your original query `?- movie(Y, M, C), member(Y, [_|year]).` it is quite clear why you get the entire database: You are trying to match the free variable `Y` with an anonymous variable `_` which *always* succeeds.

If on the other hand you have a list of years to match instead of a year from which on to find all movies, member/2 is indeed a good choice for your query:

```
?- member(Y,[1999,2000,2001]), movie(year(Y), M, C).
C = cast([actor(kevin,spacey),actor(annette,bening),actor(wes,bentley)]),
M = title([american,beauty]),
Y = 1999 ? ;
C = cast([actor(orlando,bloom),actor(sean,bean)]),
M = title([lord,of,the,rings]),
Y = 2001 ? ;
no
```

Note that the variable `Y` must be part of the term `year(Y)` in order to match years or the list you are using as 2nd argument of member/2
must contain the years in the form `year(Y)`:

```
?- member(Y,[year(1999),year(2000),year(2001)]), movie(Y, M, C).
C = cast([actor(kevin,spacey),actor(annette,bening),actor(wes,bentley)]),
M = title([american,beauty]),
Y = year(1999) ? ;
C = cast([actor(orlando,bloom),actor(sean,bean)]),
M = title([lord,of,the,rings]),
Y = year(2001) ? ;
no
```

Also note that in these examples the goals #>=/2 and member/2 appear in front of the goal movie/3. Both of these goals are used as constraints: Search the movie database for matching years instead of match all movies and then check for matching years. Putting cheap constraints first can make a big difference e.g. when the actual predicate you want to query yields infinitely many results.